# Opensaml 4.2.0 not directly found in maven central

Tags: opensaml

Searched a lot in the web. But couldn't find the solution for opensaml 4.2.0 to be used in the springboot application.

I referred the below link. Unfortunately it din't work for me.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/saml2/login/build.gradle
My build.gradle file is

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}
group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases/" }
}
dependencies {
constraints {
        implementation "org.opensaml:opensaml-core:4.2.0"
        implementation "org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-api:4.2.0"
        implementation "org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:4.2.0"
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-saml2-service-provider'
    implementation 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

But am getting the error in the eclipse problem page:
Unresolved dependency: org.opensaml:opensaml-saml-impl:4.2.0

I need to use the opensaml...4.20 jars in my project.
Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.